# AlloyUI FormBuilder - Adding futher field types

Tags: formbuilder, alloy-ui

Is it possible to add further field types to AlloyUI FormBuilder like Datepicker and Timepicker?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: [ask]